# org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: mdl.Complaint.jobDone

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried to use hibanate and save values in SQL DB.It has one database and 3 tbales that tables are called Complaint,JobDone and JobCard.

There is a One-to-One relationship between Complaint and JobDone.
There is a Many-to-One relationship between Complaint and JobCard.

when I'm runing my project I got following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: mdl.Complaint.jobDone
    at org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
```

**below codes are possible or not?

what is the better way write these code?**

JobCard.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JobCard", catalog = "jobcard", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "vehicleNumber"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "date"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "model"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "groupLeader"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "testBy"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "jobDirector"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "finishDate") })
public class JobCard implements Serializable{
    private Integer jobNumber;
    private String vehicleNumber;
    private Integer date;
    private String model;
    private String groupLeader;
    private String testBy;
    private String jobDirector;
    private Integer finishDate;
    private Set<Complaint> complaints = new HashSet<Complaint>(0);
    /**
     * @return the jobNumber
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "jobNumber", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getJobNumber() {
        return jobNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobNumber the jobNumber to set
     */
    public void setJobNumber(Integer jobNumber) {
        this.jobNumber = jobNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the vehicleNumber
     */
    public String getVehicleNumber() {
        return vehicleNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param vehicleNumber the vehicleNumber to set
     */
    public void setVehicleNumber(String vehicleNumber) {
        this.vehicleNumber = vehicleNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    public Integer getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param date the date to set
     */
    public void setDate(Integer date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    /**
     * @return the model
     */
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    /**
     * @param model the model to set
     */
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    /**
     * @return the groupLeader
     */
    public String getGroupLeader() {
        return groupLeader;
    }

    /**
     * @param groupLeader the groupLeader to set
     */
    public void setGroupLeader(String groupLeader) {
        this.groupLeader = groupLeader;
    }

    /**
     * @return the testBy
     */
    public String getTestBy() {
        return testBy;
    }

    /**
     * @param testBy the testBy to set
     */
    public void setTestBy(String testBy) {
        this.testBy = testBy;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jobDirector
     */
    public String getJobDirector() {
        return jobDirector;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobDirector the jobDirector to set
     */
    public void setJobDirector(String jobDirector) {
        this.jobDirector = jobDirector;
    }

    /**
     * @return the finishDate
     */
    public Integer getFinishDate() {
        return finishDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param finishDate the finishDate to set
     */
    public void setFinishDate(Integer finishDate) {
        this.finishDate = finishDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the complaints
     */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "jobCard")
    public Set<Complaint> getComplaints() {
        return complaints;
    }

    /**
     * @param complaints the complaints to set
     */
    public void setComplaints(Set<Complaint> complaints) {
        this.complaints = complaints;
    }


}
```

JobDone.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JobDone", catalog = "jobcard", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "nature"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "amount") })
public class JobDone implements Serializable{
    private Integer jobDone_id;
    private String nature;
    private Integer amount;
    private Complaint complaint;

    /**
     * @return the jobDone_id
     */
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "complaint"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "jobDone_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getJobDone_id() {
        return jobDone_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobDone_id the jobDone_id to set
     */
    public void setJobDone_id(Integer jobDone_id) {
        this.jobDone_id = jobDone_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nature
     */
    public String getNature() {
        return nature;
    }

    /**
     * @param nature the nature to set
     */
    public void setNature(String nature) {
        this.nature = nature;
    }

    /**
     * @return the amount
     */
    public Integer getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    /**
     * @param amount the amount to set
     */
    public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    /**
     * @return the complaint
     */

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "jobDone", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Complaint getComplaint() {
        return complaint;
    }

    /**
     * @param complaint the complaint to set
     */
    public void setComplaint(Complaint complaint) {
        this.complaint = complaint;
    }
}
```

Complaint.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Complaint", catalog = "jobcard")
public class Complaint implements Serializable{
    private Integer complaint_id;
    private String nature;
    private String instruction;
    private JobDone jobDone;
    private JobCard jobCard;

    /**
     * @return the complaint_id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "complaint_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getComplaint_id() {
        return complaint_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param complaint_id the complaint_id to set
     */
    public void setComplaint_id(Integer complaint_id) {
        this.complaint_id = complaint_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nature
     */
    public String getNature() {
        return nature;
    }

    /**
     * @param nature the nature to set
     */
    public void setNature(String nature) {
        this.nature = nature;
    }

    /**
     * @return the instruction
     */
    public String getInstruction() {
        return instruction;
    }

    /**
     * @param instruction the instruction to set
     */
    public void setInstruction(String instruction) {
        this.instruction = instruction;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jobDone
     */
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public JobDone getJobDone() {
        return jobDone;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobDone the jobDone to set
     */
    public void setJobDone(JobDone jobDone) {
        this.jobDone = jobDone;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jobCard
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobNumber", nullable = false)
    public JobCard getJobCard() {
        return jobCard;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobCard the jobCard to set
     */
    public void setJobCard(JobCard jobCard) {
        this.jobCard = jobCard;
    }

}
```

SQl query:

```
CREATE DATABASE jobcard;
USE jobcard;
CREATE TABLE JobCard(
    customer_id varchar(10),
    grade_id varchar(10),
    jobNumber int(10) primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vehicleNumber varchar(10),
    date int,
    model varchar(100),
    groupLeader varchar(100),
    testBy varchar(100),
    jobDirector varchar(100),
    finishDate int,
    constraint foreign key(customer_id) references Customer(customer_id) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade    ,
    constraint foreign key(grade_id) references Grade(grade_id) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade    
);
CREATE TABLE Complaint(
    jobNumber int(100),
    complaint_id int(10) primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nature varchar(200),
    instruction varchar(200),
    constraint foreign key(jobNumber) references JobCard(jobNumber) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade  
);

CREATE TABLE JobDone(
    complaint_id int(10),
    jobDone_id int(10) primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nature varchar(200),
    amount int,
    constraint foreign key(complaint_id) references Complaint(complaint_id) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade     
);
```

And I create hibernate.cfg.xml file and I mapped fully qualified class name every classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save an instance with embedded object that is transient - unknown for hibernate (usually it means that ID is null). You must save this embedded object first.

So if you want to save Complaint to database you must save embedded JobCard and JobDone first, before saving Complaint.